# Creating worksheet change with KeyCells from different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a worksheet that will create columns depending on the value of a cell.  So if I input 10, 10 columns will be created.  I was able to achieve that, however, I would like the range to pull from a different worksheet.  I wasn't sure if that was possible and if so, how to do it.  If it is not, is there a way to have the sheet refresh once I enter that specific sheet so I can link that value to each sheet it is needed?  I will have multiple sheets that will depend on this value to display information.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range, ColNum As Long, TotalCol As Long, LeftFixedCol As Long
Dim Rng As Range, c As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("B2")
 
If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If IsNumeric(KeyCells.Value) = False Then Exit Sub
 

ColNum = KeyCells.Value
If ColNum <= 0 Then Exit Sub
Set Rng = Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, Columns.Count))
Set c = Rng.Find("END")     
If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
TotalCol = c.Column
LeftFixedCol = 1 


Dim i As Integer
If TotalCol < LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Then 
        For i = TotalCol To LeftFixedCol + ColNum
        Columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(4, i).Value = "Member" & i - LeftFixedCol 
        Cells(5, i).Value = "=DATA!$A$2"
        Cells(6, i).Value = "=OFFSET(DATA!$C$2,COLUMN()-2,0)"
        Cells(7, i).Value = "=OFFSET(DATA!$D$2,COLUMN()-2,0)"
        Cells(8, i).Value = "=OFFSET(DATA!$E$2,COLUMN()-2,0)"
        Cells(10, i).Value = "=OFFSET(DATA!$F$2,COLUMN()-2,0)"
        Cells(12, i).Value = "=OFFSET(DATA!$G$2,COLUMN()-2,0)"
        Cells(13, i).Value = "=OFFSET(DATA!$H$2,COLUMN()-2,0)"
        Cells(14, i).Value = "=OFFSET(DATA!$I$2,COLUMN()-2,0)"
        Next i
End If
If TotalCol > LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Then 
        For i = TotalCol - 1 To LeftFixedCol + ColNum + 1 Step -1
            Columns(i).Delete
        Next i

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow your question correctly, but you can reference another worksheet when using VBA commands, example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 3).Font.Size = 14
```

You can also do that by index:

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(5, 3).Value = 2
```

This way you could pull the range from a different Worksheet.